# Why can I add unknown properties to the return value of a function type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I want to declare a simple function type that returns an object.

```
type F = () => {n: number, s: string};
```

Then I instantiate a value of this type, ensuring it is of type `F`.

```
const f: F = () => {
  return {n: 1, s: 's', r: 10};
};
```

Question: **Why doesn't this give a compilation error?**

I would expect it to complain about the `r` property in the returned value as being *unknown* with respect to the return type of `F`, since `F` is declared to return a type `{n: number, s: string}` which does not have an `r` property.

Comment: Please see the answers to the linked questions for more information.